# Discord messages.read in Node.js

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, discord, discord.js

Does anyone know how to use discord's Oauth2 messages.read scope with Node?

Discord's documentation only mentions this once, and I can't find anything about it anywhere else.

More characters to reach character minimumMore characters to reach character minimumMore characters to reach character minimumMore characters to reach character minimumMore characters to reach character minimumMore characters to reach character minimum

Comment: You should check a tutorial like [Getting started with OAuth2](https://discordjs.guide/oauth2/#authorization-code-grant-flow) and add messages.read to the scope.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2) has a section on OAuth2 scopes. In a nutshell, to be able to read the messages of a user, your client app needs to obtain an access token with this scope. For this, you probably need to get an approval from the user (once your client goes through the Authorization Code Flow). Please follow the official documentation for more info. If you need to understand how OAuth2 Authorization Code Flow works, there are plenty of other resources online.

Comment: I know enough about Oauth2, but what api url would I use? The identity scope has a /users/@me url in the description, but the messages.read description doesn't have one. Or am I just overthinking this and is this scope what gives bots permissions to read messages?